# Addition of header in dynamically created sortable list in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, jsp, jquery-ui

I am creating two sortable list dynamically and in accordion-body i need to add heading for both the list so that we can differentiate between those list's location. (visually)
i am not able add header as it is not aligning with these below given list.

```
    <div id="accordion" class="accordionDiv">
        <div class="accordion-heading">
            <a class="accordion-toggle" style="color: black" id="sortable"
                data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion2" href="#"> <spring:message
                    code="lbl.methodToExecute" />
            </a>
        </div>
        <div id="accordionBody" class="accordion-body collapse">
            <ul id="sortable1" class="connectedSortable">
            </ul>
            <ul id="sortable2" class="connectedSortable">
            </ul>

        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Could you post the js code that you have tried ?

Comment: i was just trying to add <h5> tag before both <ul> tag, but alignment problem forcing me to remove those.